# Android Market install referrer is empty for installs from market. Is it a bug or normal behavior?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I've created custom broadcast receiver

It get referrer only when link is opened using android market app on the phone. When user install app from market website referrer is emtpy, but it present in market url.

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: `user install app from market website` do you mean that when user navigates to android market from PC and clicks install (logged in, device connected to user account)?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this site:

http://www.localytics.com/docs/android-market-campaign-analytics/

It has a code example for implementing a referal and a lot of other interesting information on this topic.

Comment: Thans Force, I read docs. However referrer is empty when app is installed from market website. So your answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In the link I have posted this issue is mentioned: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16006

Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: And all three required values (source, medium, campaign) were passed?